# Jquery not loading in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a problem loading jQuery into laravel app. I tried checking if it's installed in the first place and I get success. Using this:

```
if (typeof jQuery == "undefined") {
  alert("JQuery is not installed");
} else {
  alert("JQuery is installed correctly!");
}
```

But then I tried checking if it's loading with code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        console.log("jQuery has loaded!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        console.log("jQuery has not loaded!");
    }
}
```

I get no response at all. What could be the problem?

This is my scripts in file (last 2 lines):

```
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bs-init.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/4-Col-Small-Slider.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/A-working-Rating-option-for-Contact-Forms.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/Add%20an%20upsell.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/add%20to%20cart%20button.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/ask%20payment%20method.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/cheque.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/currency.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/easings.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/flickity%20pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/flickity.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/meals%20sizes.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/menu.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/modal.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/plans.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/realtime%20typing%20card%20expires.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/realtime%20typing%20card%20number.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/realtime%20typing%20cardholder%20cvc.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/realtime%20typing%20cardholder.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/realtime%20typing.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/remove%20product%20from%20cart.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/section%20click.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/SlideShow.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/Swiper-Slider-Card-For-Blog-Or-Product.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/Swiper-Slider.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/swiper.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/swipermin.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/switches%20on%20add%20a%20meal%20page.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/theme.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/time.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/upsell.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using Laravel mix, it seems there's problem somewhere in `app.js` I suppose.

I managed to load jQuery, I get success message, but it still doesn't work. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#category_image").on("change", function () {
        var image = $("#category_image");
        var preview = $("#preview-image");
        var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
        preview).css("background-image", 'url('+objectURL+')');
    }) 
});
```

This code doesn't work, unless I messed something up. If I use plain javascript `onchange` and I use jQuery `id` selector it works. Am I doing this function wrong?

Comment: Try to move jquery `<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the first script.

Comment: Thanks for response, 
I changed it, still the same

Comment: Managed to get it to load, I get message that jQuery is loaded, but it still doesn't work

Comment: But _why_ you need to check it? Don't you always load same set of libraries in your own code?

Comment: Just to make sure it is actually loading, because it wasn't working for me. But now I realised I did some stupid mistakes, it's all fixed now...

Comment: Try loading jquery through their CDN to rule out a problem with your assets